# Android studio naming convention refactoring

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, naming-conventions

I have to support an old project with huge code base and there is `m` prefix naming conventing there, however I want to rename all fields in a project to follow common java naming style.

Does android studio supports such refactoring?

Comment: Yeah structural search and replace is what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!

Shift +F6 (Keyboard shortcut for refactoring!)

Ctrl + Shift +R (Search and Replace All)

Comment: this is just renaming one field, what if you have thousands